# Copying Excel data and transposing to another worksheet in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel

```
''''''''Public Variables Module'''''''

    Public oXL As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Public oWB As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Public oSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

''''''''End Public Variables Module''''''''


'''''''''Form1.vb'''''''''''


        oXL = New Excel.Application
        oXL.Visible = True        

 oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add


        oSheet = oWB.ActiveSheet

        oWB.Worksheets(1).range("a1").select()
        oWB.Worksheets(1).Paste()

        oSheet.UsedRange.Copy()
        oWB.Worksheets.Add()
        oWB.Worksheets("Sheet2").range("a1").select()
        oWB.Worksheets("Sheet2").PasteSpecial(Transpose:=True)


'''''''''End Form1.vb'''''''''''
```

It's crashing on the pastespecial line with error:

Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

I've tried skipping the range("a1").select step on sheet2 to no avail.

I should add that the reason I am pasting data to the first worksheet before re-copying it and pasting to the second is because the data is already on the the clipboard from an external application, and I am assuming it isn't possible to transpose it on the initial paste when it's data from an external source.

If I change the pastespecial to a normal paste, it works fine. So I am assuming something is wrong with my pastespecial command.

I have tried copying multiple forms of data to my clipboard before running the app so it's not related to a specific set of data being untransposable.

I have also verified that it is in fact selecting the usedrange before copying (vs the entire sheet).

Comment: Is there some err msg that is more grokkable than HResult etc.?

Comment: How would I pull that up? The most I found was "A system.runtime.interopservices.COMException was thrown" and then it displays that error.

If the error is not clear, does anything in that line of code jump out as wrong that might be causing an issue?

Comment: Sine paste works (as opposed to pastespecial), what does the latter give you that you need? I'm working with C# and Excel, and I don't know VB at all, but the "Transpose:=True" does look strange to me - is it really supposed to have that Pascal-like syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, needed to specify a range as well:

```
oWB.Worksheets("Sheet2").range("a1").PasteSpecial(Transpose:=True)
```